# How do I resolve fatal: bad object refs/heads/1477/feature/client-custom-query 2 in my local (remote) repo?

Tags: git

Whenever I checkout at the master branch and execute `git pull` it returns:

```
fatal: bad object refs/heads/1477/feature-client-custom-query 2
```

The same fatal returns when I run `git gc`

I have the branch `1477/feature-client-custom-query` locally and have pushed all its commits to origin. I'm not sure why it has the  `2` at the end of the fatal message. My objective is to get my local copy of master in sync with origin. As of now, it is several commits behind.

When I execute `git reset --hard origin/master` it returns:

```
HEAD is now at 3be1bd5dc0 commit message
```

But this is not the most recent commit in origin/master. How can I get the head up to date on my local copy?

Answer (score 2):

> I have the branch `1477/feature-client-custom-query` locally and have pushed all its commits to origin. I'm not sure why it has the  `2` at the end of the fatal message.

This is one of the symptoms displayed for a Git repository that has been damaged by cloud-synchronizing software such as OneDrive, iCloud, Dropbox, etc.  (Don't store Git repositories here as they *will* get damaged.  Via Murphy's Law, this usually happens right before the big demo.)

To fix it, you can probably (1) move the repository out to a safe location, then (2) remove the `.git/refs/heads/1477/feature-client-custom-query 2` file that the cloud-syncing software created.  Run `git fsck` to check everything else.  If it's too heavily damaged, just remove it and re-clone.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to do a re-clone. The path of my repo is outside of any sync software but there are probably other ways to damage a repo. I figured the 2 after the branch name was a symptom of something not good. It has been a chaotic two weeks and I've been jumping around the repo like a crazy man. A re-clone is the path of least resistance - one of the things I love about dev work - version control. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pull all changes with `rebase`

- `git pull --rebase origin master`
- Then solve the conflicts
- `git add <file_name> OR git add .`
- `git rebase --continue`
- if you still the conflicts then repeat 2nd to 4th steps

OR
you can directly do with force pull

- `git pull -f origin master`

Comment: Both options returned the same fatal as in the OP. There is another error after the fatal that says `error: github.com:project/name.git did not send all necessary objects`. Further `git status` returns `up to date with 'origin/master'` but it is not. I'm still several commit s behind.